# Apache starts on Ubuntu under incorrect user

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

I have Ubuntu hosting. There is a user *user1* which is sudoer.

In my apache2 configuration in envvars config I have default config which defines

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

By executing command

```
ps -efH | grep apache
```

I'm getting all processes launched from root

```
root     15378 15358  0 16:33 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     15379 15358  0 16:33 ?        00:00:00     /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

When I'm adding to the php code

```
echo exec('whoami');
```

I'm getting *user1*

How can it be? I've tried to restart workstation, restart service without any luck

UPDATE 1.
httpd.conf

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

I'm starting by one of these:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Where are the rest of the Apache processes?

Comment: there are a lot of Apache processes. all of them are launched from root

Comment: Can you edit your listing of Apache processes by including the output of `ps -elf | sed -n "1p;/apach[e]/p;"`? This includes the Parent PID for each process. Also, show the results of `grep -w User -R /etc/apache2/` so we can see that there isn't a second `User` directive over-riding your configuration.